# Difference of :abs_g2_s: and :abs_g2_s: in arm64 assembly relocation specifiers

Tags: assembly, arm64

I saw https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armclang_ref/armclang_ref_zvb1510926525383.htm, but I can't exactly understand the relocation specifiers.
I can understand some of it. For example, in the example below, `movw r0, #:lower16:sym(sbrel)` seems to mean "move lower 16 bits of the section based relative address of sym to r0". And `adrp x0, #:got:sym` seems to say "move the page address(long aparted variable's address, bits 11 to 0 filled with zero) of the value sym in got(global object table))`.

```
  // Load the base-relative address of 'sym' (used for 'RWPI'
  // position-independent code) into r0 using movw and movt:
  movw r0, #:lower16:sym(sbrel)
  movt r0, #:upper16:sym(sbrel)

  // Load the address of 'sym' from the GOT using ADRP and LDR (used for
  // position-independent code on AArch64):
  adrp x0, #:got:sym
  ldr x0, [x0, #:got_lo12:sym]
```

Does the `#` mean `address of`? (I can guess only from the comments in the example).
Another question is : What is the difference of `:abs_g2:` and `:abs_g2_s:`? The first one is taking the variable's bits 47:32. Then what is abs_g2_s? Taking the bits 47:32 with sign extension? I guess filling the upper bits with the same top bit?

```
Relocation specifier    Relocation type Bits to use Overflow checked
:abs_g2:    Absolute    [47:32] Yes
:abs_g2_s:  Absolute, signed    [47:32] Yes
```

Comment: Normally `#` is the prefix for an immediate operand, e.g. `add x0, x0, #4`.  In GAS it's optional, but other AArch64 assemblers might require it.  However, GAS doesn't allow it for `adrp`, because the operand there is supposed to be a label, not an immediate.

Comment: yes I've seen for long # is used for immediate values. but the comment in the example says it's address so I asked if it has any special use..

Comment: In `ldr x0, [x0, #:got_lo12:sym]` it is an immediate integer that is the low 12 bits of the address of `sym` (or its GOT entry).  But in general I know of no significance for `#` other than to indicate an immediate.  I can't imagine that it would mean "address of"; how would that even work in assembler?  Every symbol is effectively an address already.

Comment: yes, right. symbols are actually addresses. so I now realize `:lower16:sym` works on the address of variable `sym` not on the value of `sym`. Thanks.